# write multiples scores on different lines using FileOutputStream

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

(API 27, android 8.1) Im new to the android world and im trying to understand why the output always write on the same first line of the .txt even tho im using a lineSeparator everytime i write on the file. Here's my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String usernameD = username.getText().toString();
        String highscore = "Score: " + scoreT + " - Cards Left: " + cLeftT + " - Username: " + usernameD;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            fos.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
            fos.write(highscore.getBytes());
            fos.flush();

            username.getText().clear();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time when you are opening fileOutputStream it rewrite old data.

To fix it, find your where you create `FileOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
```

and set the boolean to `true`. That way, the data you write will be appended to the end of the file, rather than overwriting what was already there.

Comment: FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, MODE_APPEND) since its a int type, but the idea was there! thx!